# What does this mean? "A matrix is diagonizable if and only if its eigenvectors are invertible."

Tags: linear-algebra

What does this mean?

> A matrix is diagonizable if and only if its eigenvectors are invertible.

Comment: Vectors are not invertible!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is ill-posed and the comments clearly explain the nature of the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is meaningless! What is true is that a $n\times n$ matrix is diagonalizable if and only if a **basis of eigenvectors** exists, that is a set of **n linearly independent eigenvectors** exists.

Comment: Then the matrix with eigenvectors as columns is invertible, it makes sense

Comment: @Berci Ah ok in that way it makes sense!

Comment: @gimusi The values held in each eigenvector don't matter when it comes to invertibility?

Comment: @PattyWatty27 Recall that if$ \vec v_1$ and $\vec v_2$ are linearly independent also $a \vec v_1$ and $b \vec v_2$  with $a,b\in \mathbb R$ with $a,b \neq 0$ are linearly independent

Comment: @Berci Actually, it means **some matrix** with eigenvectors as columns is invertible. There are many square matrices with eigenvectors as columns that are not invertible, but diagonalizable means that there is **some** such matrix which is invertible.

Answer (score 2):

An $n \times n$ matrix $A$ is diagonizable i.e., there exists a matrix $P$ such that $A = P^{-1}DP$ where $D$ is a diagonal matrix; iff there are $n$ linearly independent eigenvectors.

A matrix can be diagonizable but not invertible i.e., have eigenvectors with eigenvalues 0, and a matrix can be invertible but no diagonizable.